# Delphi - translate load of TRESTRequest to CURL command

Tags: api, rest, delphi

I am writing code to POST data to a REST API with the REST library. I want to be able to debug by using CURL commands. So, how can I translate the load of TRESTRequest into a CURL command, including the headers?
I am using Delphi 11.
Thanks.

Comment: Delphi has no built-in support for that and I don't know any library for this job. You probably have to write one yourself.

Comment: A lot use a separate program like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/product/rest-client/) to work on the various calls and make sure they understand an API. They then translate the now known working calls from that tool to whatever else.